# Normal closure of a subgroup that is identical to its commutator subgroup inherits this property

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

#### Problem statement

Let $A$ be a subgroup of $G$. It is known that $A = A^{(1)}$, where $A^{(1)}$ is $A$'s commutator subgroup.

**Normal closure** of $A$ is defined as $N(A) := \left\langle g A g^{-1} \ | \  g \in G \right\rangle$.

How do I prove that $N(A) = N(A)^{(1)}$?

#### My thoughts so far

It is evident that $N(A)^{(1)} \subset N(A)$, so it is only needed to prove the reverse inclusion, that is
$$\forall z \in N(A) \ \ z = [x_1, y_1]^{\varepsilon_1} \dots [x_n, y_n]^{\varepsilon_n};\ \varepsilon_i \in \{-1, 0, 1\};\ x_i, y_i \in N(A)$$

I have tried to prove this at least for the simplest case, when $z = g a g^{-1};\ a \in A, g \in G$ and $a = [a_1, b_1];\ a_1, b_1 \in A$, but even there I am stuck.

I believe if I could do that, some form of induction could be used to prove the rest, still I am struggling with the "base case".

Is this approach even viable? How do I do this?

Comment: The standard notation for the normal closure is $A^G$; $N(A)$ is too likely to be confused with the normalizer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can complete your step by noting that: $[x,y]^g = [x^g,y^g]$ for all $x,y,g\in G$.

A bit easier: you know every element of $A$ is a product of commutators of elements of $A$; hence you know that every element of $gAg^{-1}$ is a product of commutators of elements of $gAg^{-1}$. Hence you know that every element of $A^G$ is...

Comment: I guess in this case $\varepsilon_i$ were mostly clouding my judgment. They are overcomplicating things, given that inverse of a commutator is a commutator itself. Therefore, since all elements of $A^g$ belong to the normal closure commutator subgroup, knowing that all elements of said subgroup are finite products of $A^g$ elements, for various $g$'s, it suffices to rewrite each factor as the product of commutators over $N(A)$, yielding that $N(A) \subset N(A)^{(1)}$ indeed.